# Is it possible in reading properties?

Tags: java, properties, resourcebundle

```
protected static ResourceBundle bankBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages.EN.properties");
```

Is it possible to read properties with dot (.) extension properties name?

Comment: *"double doted properties name"*  By 'doted' DYM 'quoted' or *"Be extremely and uncritically fond of"* in the past tense?

Comment: I am sure you intend something diffentent than the conventional internationalisation, but convention would have been "messages_en.properties" (en when language, EN when country).

Comment: Better than thanking me, is fixing it.  You can [edit your own post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17340428/edit), of course..

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks a lot for your comments I resolved my problem with your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually ResourceBundle accepts only fully qualified base name of the bundle, with no file extension. In this case it will try to load the bundle of files like this

```
messages/EN/properties.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Property class of java:

**(Updated from comments)**

```
Properties prop = new Properties(); 
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); 
InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("/messages.EN.properties");
prop.load(stream);
```

Comment: roperties prop = new Properties();
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();           
InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("/messages.EN.properties");
prop.load(stream);

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, you can use Properties class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Also you can refer this sample of Code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();           
InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("/messages.EN.properties");
prop.load(stream);
```